# Mocking a python dict with a dict of mocks

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

I want to mock a dict `RESOURCES` imported from another module. The method under test gets an object stored in the dict `RESOURCES` and calls that object's method `query()`. I want to test that `query()` is being called with the proper arguments, so the mocked `RESOURCES` needs to store mock objects that I can assert on.

How do I achieve this?

When I run the following code, `assert_called_with` fails because `query` is never called.

mymodule.py

```
from othermodule import RESOURCES # just a dict
 
def get_resource(date):
    resource = RESOURCES["Prod"]
    return resource.query(date)
```

test_mymodule.py

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, Mock, patch
from mymodule import get_resource
import pytest

@patch("mymodule.RESOURCES")
def test_get_resources(mock_resources):
    mock_prod_resource = Mock()
    mock_prod_resource.query = Mock(return_value=[1, 2])
    d = {"Prod": mock_prod_resource}
    mock_resources.__getitem__.side_effect = d.__getitem__

    result = get_resource("2020-11-01")

    mock_prod_resource.query.assert_called_with("2020-11-01")
    assert result == [1, 2]
```

Comment: You've got a typo in your code: `mock_resource.__getitem__...` should be `mock_resources.__getitem__...` (note the "s"). And the line `mock_resource = MagicMock()` is not needed - you already have the mock.

Comment: ahh it works now, thank you!